# How to use Bootstrap 5 to automatically transform a stack of div into a masonry layout?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am working with a theme template for blogger.com. I would like to have the blog posts on the home page to be like a masonry as show in the attached picture. Due to limitation with Blogger, it's not easy to calculate on the server side so to help decide col or col-4 classes to be deployed. Furthermore, to wrap around one div and two div with  can be difficult with blogger.com.

I suppose I can use Javascript to move these html components around. However, before I do so, I am wondering if there is any automatic way where Bootstrap can transform a simple list of div into a masonry stack like shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Unless you had elements with different heights, I would not necessarily call this a masonry layout. The second "div 1" on the right side surely should be div 4 instead, and then this simply means you want different column widths for certain elements, at certain breakpoints. Bootstrap already comes perfectly equipped to do this - if blogger's system doesn't let you easily apply the necessary classes, that's not really bootstrap's fault. But using `:nth-child` selectors, you should be able to write your own rules that apply the necessary styling, without the ability to add extra classes.

Comment: You are right, 2nd div 1 should be Div 4. It's a typo. I am not saying it's Bootstrap's fault. It's the rather cumbersome limitation of blogger.com's fault. If I were to do it in php or python it would be a simple looping of the index (or the nth element). I do think some kind of advance css rules like nth-child may be a solution and avoid writing javascript I am just a beginner for both but css seems easier. Thanks and I'll explore more into that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .col-sm-6:nth-child(3n+1) {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
        border: solid 10px #ffffff;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-3 bg-primary text-white">.col</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great and simple solution. You have included TWO html structure with the top commented out. I suppose that was the original web page that is related to my  question and the bottom one would be a customised solution for my question! It works great on running on code snippet and I am going to try it out on my blog template. Thanks.

Comment: Just applied it to my blog template. Works like a charm! There is no need to include col-12 however. Using only col-6 works already.

Comment: @SSuen "col-12" using for small devices like mobile. If we wall all items in full width.

Comment: Thanks. I recognise the use of col-12. it is needed for small device.

Comment: then can you please up vote that solution @SSuen

Comment: I have already done so before. May be someone else down voted it?